# Graphs changing intervals on hover?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, chart.js

Using Chartjs and bootstrap4. Getting the data from an ajax call.

Upon page load, I load a graph. I have no problems with this graph.

[image]

To change the frequency of the graph, I have a row of buttons. I use a button click, get the ID of that button, and inside the button click use a switch statement to match the IDs and initiate the appropriate ajax call to get the data required and print that to the graph.

For the most part, this works. However, after I've clicked on a button in the row below, and I hover my mouse over the graph, the graph will change frequencies on hover. I have no idea what could be causing this.

```
$("button[name='graphBTN']" ).on('click', function(){
            console.log("You entered: " + this.id);   

            switch(this.id) {
                case '1DChartBTN':

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" + searchTerm + "/chart/1d",
                        method: 'GET',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data)
                            var minute = [];
                            var price = [];


                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                minute.push(data[i].minute);
                                price.push(data[i].low);   
                            }

                            $('#graphName').html("1 day graph of " + searchTerm.toUpperCase());

                            var chart = $('#chart');

                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'white';
                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Raleway';

                            var oneDayChart = new Chart(chart, {
                                type: 'line',
                                data: {
                                    labels: minute,
                                    datasets: [
                                        {
                                            data: price,
                                            label: 'Average Price',
                                            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                                            pointRadius: '1',
                                            pointBorderColor: 'white',
                                            pointBackgroundColor: 'red'
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                                options: {
                                    scales: {
                                        yAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }],
                                        xAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log("Error!" + error);
                        }
                    });

                    break;

                case '1MChartBTN':

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" + searchTerm + "/chart/1m",
                        method: 'GET',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data)
                            var dates = [];
                            var close = [];


                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                dates.push(data[i].date);
                                close.push(data[i].close);   
                            }

                            $('#graphName').html("1 month graph of " + searchTerm.toUpperCase());

                            var chart = $('#chart');

                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'white';
                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Raleway';

                            var oneMonthChart = new Chart(chart, {
                                type: 'line',
                                data: {
                                    labels: dates,
                                    datasets: [
                                        {
                                            data: close,
                                            label: 'Close Price',
                                            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                                            pointRadius: '1',
                                            pointBorderColor: 'white',
                                            pointBackgroundColor: 'red'
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                                options: {
                                    scales: {
                                        yAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }],
                                        xAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log("Error!" + error);
                        }
                    });

                    break;

                case '3MChartBTN':
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" + searchTerm + "/chart/3m",
                        method: 'GET',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data)
                            var dates = [];
                            var close = [];


                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                dates.push(data[i].date);
                                close.push(data[i].close);   
                            }

                            $('#graphName').html("3 month graph of " + searchTerm.toUpperCase());

                            var chart = $('#chart');

                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'white';
                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Raleway';

                            var threeMonthChart = new Chart(chart, {
                                type: 'line',
                                data: {
                                    labels: dates,
                                    datasets: [
                                        {
                                            data: close,
                                            label: 'Close Price',
                                            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                                            pointRadius: '1',
                                            pointBorderColor: 'white',
                                            pointBackgroundColor: 'red'
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                                options: {
                                    scales: {
                                        yAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }],
                                        xAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log("Error!" + error);
                        }
                    });

                    break;

                case '6MChartBTN':

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" + searchTerm + "/chart/6m",
                        method: 'GET',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data)
                            var dates = [];
                            var close = [];


                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                dates.push(data[i].date);
                                close.push(data[i].close);   
                            }

                            $('#graphName').html("6 month graph of " + searchTerm.toUpperCase());

                            var chart = $('#chart');

                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'white';
                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Raleway';

                            var sixMonthChart = new Chart(chart, {
                                type: 'line',
                                data: {
                                    labels: dates,
                                    datasets: [
                                        {
                                            data: close,
                                            label: 'Close Price',
                                            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                                            pointRadius: '1',
                                            pointBorderColor: 'white',
                                            pointBackgroundColor: 'red'
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                                options: {
                                    scales: {
                                        yAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }],
                                        xAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log("Error!" + error);
                        }
                    });

                    break;

                case 'YTDChartBTN':

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" + searchTerm + "/chart/ytd",
                        method: 'GET',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data)
                            var dates = [];
                            var close = [];


                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                dates.push(data[i].date);
                                close.push(data[i].close);   
                            }

                            $('#graphName').html("YTD graph of " + searchTerm.toUpperCase());

                            var chart = $('#chart');

                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'white';
                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Raleway';

                            var ytdChart = new Chart(chart, {
                                type: 'line',
                                data: {
                                    labels: dates,
                                    datasets: [
                                        {
                                            data: close,
                                            label: 'Close Price',
                                            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                                            pointRadius: '1',
                                            pointBorderColor: 'white',
                                            pointBackgroundColor: 'red'
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                                options: {
                                    scales: {
                                        yAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }],
                                        xAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log("Error!" + error);
                        }
                    });

                    break;

                case '1YChartBTN':

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" + searchTerm + "/chart/1y",
                        method: 'GET',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data)
                            var dates = [];
                            var close = [];


                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                dates.push(data[i].date);
                                close.push(data[i].close);   
                            }

                            $('#graphName').html("1 year graph of " + searchTerm.toUpperCase());

                            var chart = $('#chart');

                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'white';
                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Raleway';

                            var oneYearChart = new Chart(chart, {
                                type: 'line',
                                data: {
                                    labels: dates,
                                    datasets: [
                                        {
                                            data: close,
                                            label: 'Close Price',
                                            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                                            pointRadius: '1',
                                            pointBorderColor: 'white',
                                            pointBackgroundColor: 'red'
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                                options: {
                                    scales: {
                                        yAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }],
                                        xAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log("Error!" + error);
                        }
                    });

                    break;

                case '2YChartBTN':

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" + searchTerm + "/chart/2y",
                        method: 'GET',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data)
                            var dates = [];
                            var close = [];


                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                dates.push(data[i].date);
                                close.push(data[i].close);   
                            }

                            $('#graphName').html("2 year graph of " + searchTerm.toUpperCase());

                            var chart = $('#chart');

                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'white';
                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Raleway';

                            var twoYearChart = new Chart(chart, {
                                type: 'line',
                                data: {
                                    labels: dates,
                                    datasets: [
                                        {
                                            data: close,
                                            label: 'Close Price',
                                            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                                            pointRadius: '1',
                                            pointBackgroundColor: 'red'
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                                options: {
                                    scales: {
                                        yAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }],
                                        xAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log("Error!" + error);
                        }
                    });

                    break;

                case '5YChartBTN':

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" + searchTerm + "/chart/5y",
                        method: 'GET',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data)
                            var dates = [];
                            var close = [];


                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                dates.push(data[i].date);
                                close.push(data[i].close);   
                            }

                            $('#graphName').html("5 year graph of " + searchTerm.toUpperCase());

                            var chart = $('#chart');

                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'white';
                            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Raleway';

                            var fiveYRChart = new Chart(chart, {
                                type: 'line',
                                data: {
                                    labels: dates,
                                    datasets: [
                                        {
                                            data: close,
                                            label: 'Close Price',
                                            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                                            pointRadius: '1',
                                            pointBackgroundColor: 'red'
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                                options: {
                                    scales: {
                                        yAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }],
                                        xAxes: [{
                                            gridLines: {
                                                color: 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
                                            }                                                        
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log("Error!" + error);
                        }
                    });

                    break;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I believe you are just drawing over the current chart without destroying the old one. So when you hover over the current chart it flickers between the previously created charts. Test it by paying attention to your first frequencies, create new ones, and see if the 'flicker' shows you the first charts data.

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to experiment with the .destroy() method but so far very unsuccessful.

Comment: I found that making the `var chart;` global and destroying it before creating new seems to work well.